# Replace string in Map key with string from Map value

Tags: java, hashmap

I have this code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Tester {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, String> data=new HashMap();
    data.put("Chance to Avoid Fire Damage when Hit", "(3-7)%");
    data.put("Chance to Avoid Cold Damage when Hit", "(6-8)%");
    data.put("Chance to Avoid Chaos Damage when Hit", "(6-7)%");
    data.put("Adds # to # Fire Damage to Spells", "{\"min\":10,\"avg\":20,\"max\":30}");
    data.put("Adds # to # Cold Damage to Curses", "{\"avg\":20,\"max\":30,\"min\":10}");
    data.put("Adds # to # Cold Damage to Curses", "{\"avg\":30,\"max\":20,\"min\":40}");
    data.put("Adds # to # Physical Damage to Weapon", "{\"min\":8,\"max\":32,\"avg\":20}");
    data.put("Curse Enemies with Vulnerability on level", "30");

}
}
```

our teacher asked us to make a method that will replace each first "#" with his min value and the second "#" with the max value
ex : "Adds 10 to 30 Fire Damage to Spells..." 
I've been doing it wrong for few hours and really need some help
this is what i've done this far (I know its probably bad):

```
public class Exe2 {
public static String replaceH(Map<String, String> mods) {
    Set<String> modss = new HashSet();
    String z="";
    String[] keys = mods.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
    String key = mods.get(keys);
    for (String n : keys) {
        if(n.contains("#")){
           z= n.replace("#",key.indexOf(5));

        }
    }
    return z;
}

}
```

Would really appreciate your help,thank you :)

Comment: Note that the real-life solution would be to use a better data structure

Comment: You don't need `toArray`, just use `keySet()` directly.

Comment: You also mixed up your variable names: your `key` variable is actually a map entry value. And you hard-coded an index, which is incorrect if position of `#` ever changes. Take a look at `Map.entrySet`, I believe it has everything you need in pretty much one place. You can take it from there pretty easy.

Comment: @Aaron, if this is an assignment, it might have a say against using external parser libraries.

Comment: You're going to have to extract the max and min from the value associated with each key.  Was your teacher kind enough to explain how to parse that data, which seems to be in an almost-but-not-quite-JSON format?

Comment: @KevinAnderson No..:(

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the old keys with a hash sign `#`, in a loop.
And insert the key with replacements from the value.

As in a loop removing and inserting at the same time may be problematic, you could build a second map with the new results, or the other way round, copy the (concerning) keys from the original map first.

To retrieve from the value minimum and maximum, one could use a regular expression pattern matching: `value.replaceFirst("...", "$1");` or more difficult `value.indexOf("max") / substring`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use respeated keys in a map so that's why I obtain three output instead of 4.

Secondly in order to make the problem more simple you should use the same pattern:

```
package tests;
import java.util.*;
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getFinal(initial(data));

    }
public static Map<String,String> initial(Map<String,String>a){
          a.put("Chance to Avoid Fire Damage when Hit","(3-7)%");
          a.put("Chance to Avoid Cold Damage when Hit", "(6-8)%");
          a.put("Chance to Avoid Chaos Damage when Hit", "(6-7)%");
          a.put("Adds # to # Fire Damage to Spells", "{\"avg\":20,\"max\":30,\"min\":10}");
          a.put("Adds # to # Cold Damage to Curses", "{\"avg\":20,\"max\":30,\"min\":10}");
          a.put("Adds # to # Cold Damage to Curses", "{\"avg\":30,\"max\":20,\"min\":40}");
          a.put("Adds # to # Physical Damage to Weapon", "{\"avg\":20,\"max\":32,\"min\":8}");
          a.put("Curse Enemies with Vulnerability on level", "30");
          return a;
      }

 public static Map<String,String>getFinal(Map<String,String>b){
         List<String>aux=new ArrayList<String>(b.keySet());
         List<String>aux1=new ArrayList<String>(b.keySet());
         for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++){
             if(aux.get(i).contains("#")){
                 String min=b.get(aux.get(i)).split(",")[2];
                 String max=b.get(aux.get(i)).split(",")[1];
                 String minVal=min.split(":")[1].replace("}","").trim();
                 String maxVal=max.split(":")[1].trim();
                 String c=aux.get(i).replaceFirst("#",minVal);
                 String d=c.replaceAll("#",maxVal);
                 System.out.println(d);
                 b.replace(aux1.get(i),c);

             }
             }

             return b;
         }
}
```

Output:

```
Adds 40 to 20 Cold Damage to Curses
Adds 8 to 32 Physical Damage to Weapon
Adds 10 to 30 Fire Damage to Spells
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public class ChangeMapKeysWithValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String, String> data=new HashMap<String, String>();
        HashMap<String, String> newData=new HashMap<String, String>();
        data.put("Chance to Avoid Fire Damage when Hit", "(3-7)%");
        data.put("Chance to Avoid Cold Damage when Hit", "(6-8)%");
        data.put("Chance to Avoid Chaos Damage when Hit", "(6-7)%");
        data.put("Adds # to # Fire Damage to Spells", "{\"min\":10,\"avg\":20,\"max\":30}");
        data.put("Adds # to # Cold Damage to Curses", "{\"avg\":20,\"max\":30,\"min\":10}");
        data.put("Adds # to # Cold Damage to Curses", "{\"avg\":30,\"max\":20,\"min\":40}");
        data.put("Adds # to # Physical Damage to Weapon", "{\"min\":8,\"max\":32,\"avg\":20}");
        data.put("Curse Enemies with Vulnerability on level", "30");

        Set<String> keySet = data.keySet();
        Iterator<String> itr = keySet.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()) {

            String key = itr.next();
            String value = data.get(key);

            if(key.contains("#")) {

                String[] valueArray = value.substring(1, value.length()-1).split(",");

                Map<String, String> valueSplitMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                valueSplitMap.put(valueArray[0].split(":")[0], valueArray[0].split(":")[1]);
                valueSplitMap.put(valueArray[1].split(":")[0], valueArray[1].split(":")[1]);
                valueSplitMap.put(valueArray[2].split(":")[0], valueArray[2].split(":")[1]);

                key = key.replace("#", valueSplitMap.get("\"min\""));
                key = key.replace("to " + valueSplitMap.get("\"min\""), "to " + valueSplitMap.get("\"max\""));                          
            }
            if(key != null && !key.isEmpty()) {

                newData.put(key, value);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(newData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you souldn't never change the original object , so could be a good pratice use it like a read only object and get the result in a new object , anyway my implementation is using json library **java-json.jar** that you can integrate to your project , and may you can show to your prof. I am sure he can appreciate it .

Below the code (shows only the result):

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Tester {

    public Tester() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static String replaceAt(String s,int pos,String val) {
        return s.substring(0, pos) + val + s.substring(pos + 1);
      }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HashMap<String, String> data=new HashMap();
        HashMap<String, String> result=new HashMap();
        data.put("Chance to Avoid Fire Damage when Hit", "(3-7)%");
        data.put("Chance to Avoid Cold Damage when Hit", "(6-8)%");
        data.put("Chance to Avoid Chaos Damage when Hit", "(6-7)%");
        data.put("Adds # to # Fire Damage to Spells", "{\"min\":10,\"avg\":20,\"max\":30}");
        data.put("Adds # to # Cold Damage to Curses", "{\"avg\":20,\"max\":30,\"min\":10}");
        data.put("Adds # to # Cold Damage to Curses", "{\"avg\":30,\"max\":20,\"min\":40}");
        data.put("Adds # to # Physical Damage to Weapon", "{\"min\":8,\"max\":32,\"avg\":20}");
        data.put("Curse Enemies with Vulnerability on level", "30");

        String[] keys = data.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);   
        for (String n : keys) {
            String value2 ="";
            String value ="";
            if(n.contains("#")){
                value = data.get(n);        
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(value);
            String[] valuekeys = JSONObject.getNames(object);
            int cont =0;
            for (String key2 : valuekeys)
            {
                if("min".equals(key2)){
                     value2 =object.get(key2).toString();
                    int pos = n.indexOf("#");               
                     n=replaceAt(n, pos, value2);
                }
                 if("max".equals(key2)){
                      value2 =object.get(key2).toString();
                     int pos = n.lastIndexOf("#");           
                    n= replaceAt(n, pos, value2);
                } 

            }
             System.out.println(n); 

        }   
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by using groovy:

```
Map<String, String> reference = [
    '1' : 'apple'  ,
    '2' : 'banana' ,
    '3' : 'pears'  ,
    '4' : 'peach'
]

'I want 1 she wants 4'.tokenize(' ')
                      .collect { references.get(it) ?: it }
                      .join(' ')

// result:
I want apple she wants peach
```

Or using following to keep the string format

```
'I like    1, she    likes    3.'
    .replaceAll("[^\\w]", "_\$0")
    .split('_')
    .collect {
        String c = it.trim()
        reference.get(c) ? it.replace(c, reference.get(c)) : it
     }
    .join()

// Result: I like    apple, she    likes    pears.
```